# Finding Patterns in continuous data

Tags: machine-learning

I'd like to find frequent patterns in data that has been created by an accelerometer of a Smart Watch.
The algorithm should return the parts of the data that occur after a pattern.
In the best case, the algorithm finds the movement automatically that shows how we open doors, grab our phone etc.

Unfortunately, until now I only was able to find algorithms that find frequent **item sets** in data.

Does anyone know a solution on how to find those patterns in **continuous** data?

Thank you very much! :)

[image: patterns]

Comment: Looks like you may want to look at the Fourier transform